# Powershell will not start or stop Windows service with nssm

Tags: powershell

i have a script made in powershell and i am using nssm to create as a service to be executed every "x" time, however when starting the service it generates error and does not execute.
I have full administrator rights and I even tried to run PowerShell as an administrator without success.

If I run the script directly it works, however using nssm it is not working.

The error that happens is this:

Start-Service: Service 'nice (nice)' start failed.
At C: \ Program Files \ NICE Systems \ nssm.ps1: 10 char: 14

- Start-Service <<<< $ serviceName

  - CategoryInfo: OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController: ServiceController) [Start-Service],
    ServiceCommandException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId: StartServiceFailed, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

**nssm.ps1**

```
$nssm = (Get-Command nssm.exe).Definition
$serviceName = 'nice'
$powershell = (Get-Command powershell.exe).Definition
$scriptPath = 'C:\Program Files\NICE Systems\script_delecao.ps1'
$arguments = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "{0}"' -f $scriptPath
& $nssm install $serviceName $powershell $arguments
& $nssm status $serviceName
Start-Service $serviceName
Get-Service $serviceName
```

**script_delecao.ps1**

```
$logPath = "C:\Program Files\NICE Systems\Logs\*\Archive\*"
    
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # SET $NDAYS WITH THE NUMBER OF DAYS TO KEEP IN LOG FOLDER.
    $nDays = 180
    
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # SET $EXTENSIONS WITH THE FILE EXTENSION TO DELETE.
    # YOU CAN COMBINE MORE THAN ONE EXTENSION: "*.LOG, *.TXT,"
    
    $Extensions = "*.log*"
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # PAY ATTENTION! IF YOU COMBINE MORE THAN ONE LOG PATH AND EXTENSIONS,
    # MAKE SURE THAT YOU ARE NOT REMOVING FILES THAT CANNOT BE DELETED 
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $PathDelete = "C:\Program Files\NICE Systems\Delecoes"
    
    while ($true) {
    
        If(!(test-path $PathDelete))
        {
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $PathDelete
        }
    
        $LogDate = (Get-Date).ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")
        $DateTime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
    
        $Files = Get-Childitem $LogPath -Include $Extensions -Recurse | Where `
        {$_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$nDays)}
    
        foreach ($File in $Files) 
        {
            if ($File -ne $NULL)
            {
                $Log = $DateTime + " - O arquivo " + $File + " foi deletado "
                $Log | Out-File -Append $PathDelete\DeleteLogFile_$LogDate.log
                Remove-Item $File.FullName| out-null
            }
        }
    
      # Add a sleep at the end of the loop to prevent the script from eating
      # too much CPU time
      $Log = $DateTime + " FINAL DO ARQUIVO "
      $Log | Out-File -Append $PathDelete\DeleteLogFile_$LogDate.log
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  `nssm.ps1` looks like a bad copy-paste.  The error shown is `Start-Service` on line 10, but I see it on line 8.  Also, the first line for `nssm.ps1` is missing a `$` before nssm.  When you indicate "If I run the script directly it works", are you referring to the nssm.ps1 or script_delecao.ps1 script?  When you indicate "however using nssm it is not working", are you referring to nssm.exe or nssm.ps1?

Comment: This error really sounds like PowerShell is not being run as an administrator, or the account context is not allowed to start services.  Check-out [this article](http://woshub.com/set-permissions-on-windows-service/).

Comment: The nssm.ps1 script line has been fixed, I am running as an administrator and still not working.

""If I run the script directly it works", are you referring to the nssm.ps1 or script_delecao.ps1 script?"  Through the script_delecao.ps1 

If I run the nssm.ps1 script it calls the nssm.exe executable, but it still returns the execution error.

Comment: I tested with Windows 10 and got the same behavior:
D:\ProgramFiles\Nice Systems> .\nssm.ps1
Service "nice" installed successfully!
SERVICE_STOPPED
Start-Service : Falha ao iniciar o serviço 'nice (nice)'.
No D:\ProgramFiles\Nice Systems\nssm.ps1:8 caractere:1
+ Start-Service $serviceName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a similar scenario where I cannot back-up Bamboo file system while it's running. My back-up executes from a rundeck server via Remote PowerShell, and even though the user has local admin rights it cannot stop and start services using NSSM. So I use this function to run the command elevated

```
ELEVAT "nssm stop bamboo"
tar --exclude=./logs --exclude=./temp --exclude=*.log --exclude=*.jar --verbose -czf E:\dropfolder\bamboo-home.tar.gz --directory=E:\bamboo-home .
ELEVAT "nssm start bamboo"
```

the function itself...

```
function ELEVAT ($command) {
    $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($command)
    configuration elevated {
        Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
        Set-StrictMode -Off
        Node localhost {
            Script execute {
                SetScript = $scriptBlock
                TestScript = {
                    if (([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
                        Write-Verbose "Verified Elevated Session"
                        return $false
                    } else {
                        Write-Verbose "Not an Elevated Session!"
                        exit 9996
                    }
                }
                GetScript = { return @{ 'Result' = 'RUN' } }
            }
        }
    }
    $mof = elevated
    Start-DscConfiguration ./elevated -Wait -Verbose -Force
    if ( $error ) { Write-Host "[ELEVAT][WARN] `$Error[] = $Error" ; $Error.clear() 
  }
}
```